# Set margins in cardview programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout, android-cardview

here is the code

```
CardView.LayoutParams layoutParams = new CardView.LayoutParams(
                CardView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, CardView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        layoutParams.setMargins(100,100,100,100);
        CardView cv = new CardView(this);
        cv.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

Where ever, from xml its working-

```
android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
```

what can be the reason? am i missing something!

i need margin for elevation of cardview

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are trying to avoid cropping elevation shadow of `CardView`.

Instead of manipulate margins, try set [cardUseCompatPadding](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/CardView.html#attr_android.support.v7.cardview:cardUseCompatPadding) to `true` and **if you are changing elevation dynamically**, you should call [setMaxCardElevation(float)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/CardView.html#setMaxCardElevation(float)) when `CardView` is initialized. (Both you can set via xml as well as programmatically).

Setting  max elevation for `CardView` let it takes up space for bigger shadow, but it also add this space for lower elevation.

---

By the way, if you want to set `LayoutParams` for some view, you need to use these one, which are corresponding to *view's parent*.

Example: There is a `TextView` inside `LinearLayout`.

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view);

LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

textView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

Comment: This code won't even compile for CardViews, which are based on FrameLayout--quite a different beast from LinearLayout.

Comment: @ScottBiggs Try to read and understand entire answer before you copy and paste the code.

Answer (score 2):

you can add elevation padding in card view

```
CardView card = new CardView(this);

LinearLayout.LayoutParams params =
    new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                  LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

card.setLayoutParams(params);
card.setContentPadding(2, 1, 2, 1);
card.setMaxCardElevation(5);
card.setCardElevation(9);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this chunk as per your requirement.

```
parentCardView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, (int) Utility.pxFromDp(getActivity(), 300)));

                ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams layoutParams =
                        (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) binding.parentCard.getLayoutParams();
                layoutParams.setMargins(16, 0, 16, 0);
                binding.parentCard.requestLayout();
```

This will set lay out height, width and then will put margin values over card view.

Comment: when you answer please give full code snippet in this Utility.pxFromDp method is missing

Comment: Oh my bad, sorry for inconvenience, for now i don't have this Util class available, you can try different Integer values there to  observe the effect, or check some pixelToDp methods for android devices to move on..

Comment: ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams cardViewMarginParams = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) holder.cardView.getLayoutParams();
            cardViewMarginParams.setMargins(12, 12, 12, 110);
            holder.cardView.requestLayout();  //Dont forget this line


This one is working good